# attach pdf mail cakepdf with tcpdf

Tags: tcpdf, cakephp-4.x

hello community I don't know how to attach a pdf generated with tcpdf to a mail using the cakepdf plugin in cakephp 4 here my action of the controller that sends the mail

```
public function register()
{
 $names = $doctor->name.' '.$doctor->last_name;
            $dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT.'register'.DS.$doctor->code_cmp, TRUE,0775);
            //this function generates the pdf
            $this->generatepdf($names,$doctor->specialty,$dir->path);
            
            $email = new Mailer('blue-profile');
            $email->setEmailFormat('html')
                ->setViewVars([
                    'names' => $names,
                    'specialty' => $doctor->specialty,
                    'user' => $doctor->code_cmp,
                    'password' => $this->request->getData('password')
                ])
                ->setFrom(['info@expertosaplv.pe' => 'Abbott'])
                ->setTo($doctor->email)
                ->setSubject('Bienvenido APLV Expertos Pediatras')
                ->viewBuilder()->setTemplate('welcome')->setLayout('default');
                if($email->send()){
                    $message['success'] = "success";
                    echo json_encode($message);
                    die();
                }
}
```

function that generates the pdf

```
public function generatepdf($names,$specialty,$dir)
{
    $this->set(compact('names','specialty','dir'));
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CakePdf.Pdf');
    $this->viewBuilder()->setOptions([
        'pdfConfig' => [
            'margin' => [
                'top' => 0,
                'bottom' => 0,
                'left' => 0,
                'right'=> 0
            ],
            'orientantion' => 'portrait',
            'download' => false,
        ]
    ]);        
    
}
```

here my template that from the pdf

```
require_once(ROOT.DS.'vendor'.DS.'tecnickcom'.DS.'tcpdf'.DS.'tcpdf.php');
require_once(ROOT.DS.'vendor'.DS.'tecnickcom'.DS.'tcpdf'.DS.'config'.DS.'tcpdf_config.php');
class PdfInvitation extends TCPDF{
public function Header() {
    $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
    $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false,0);
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break,$bMargin);
    $this->setPageMark();
   }
}
 $img = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'fond-pdf-notify.jpg';
 $pdf = new PdfInvitation('P',PDF_UNIT,PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,TRUE,'UTF-8',FALSE);
 ////code pdf
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->lastPage();
 $file = $pdf->Output('Diplomas-Eval-SER.pdf', 'S');
 //I saw this code in the plugin documentation
 $CakePdf = new \CakePdf\Pdf\CakePdf();
 $CakePdf->template(DS.'Doctors'.DS.'pdf'.DS.'invitation','invitation');
 $CakePdf->write($dir.DS.$file);
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the PDF correctly generated and saved in the expected folder?

Comment: if I execute it from the navigated yes but when I do it executing the `register()` action it does not generate it